# RSpec test of hash failing due to symbol, not Rails

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec, symbols

I am not using Rails, just Ruby & RSpec and trying to pass a hash pair test. The right result is coming through on IRB, but the test keeps including a semi-colon that makes the test fail.

Here is the RSpec test:

```
 describe Menu do
      let(:menu) { described_class.new }
      let(:book) { double :book, name: 'Clockwise to Titan', price: 6 }

      it 'can add a dish to the menu list' do
        menu.add(book)
        expect(menu.list).to eq({'Clockwise to Titan': 6})
      end
    end
```

Here is the failure:

```
Failures:

1) Menu can add a dish to the menu list
   Failure/Error: expect(menu.list).to eq({'Clockwise to Titan': 6})

   expected: {:"Clockwise to Titan"=>6}
        got: {"Clockwise to Titan"=>6}

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -:"Clockwise to Titan" => 6,
   +"Clockwise to Titan" => 6,

 # ./spec/menu_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have found a number of references on Stack Overflow to a similar problem solved by HashWithIndifferentAccess, but I am not using Rails. Also, the sometimes-suggested stringify_keys method is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code it looks like, you should change:

```
expect(menu.list).to eq({'Clockwise to Titan': 6})
```

to

```
expect(menu.list).to eq({'Clockwise to Titan' => 6})
```

to make the spec pass.

The problem in your case is, you defined a `hash` where a key is not a `String`, but a `Symbol`.

Consider this:

```
{'Clockwise to Titan': 6} == {:'Clockwise to Titan' => 6}
```

but

```
{'Clockwise to Titan': 6} != {'Clockwise to Titan' => 6}
```

Hope this helps!